# Flutter driver interacting with native elements

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-test

I'm having difficult to test using Flutter Driver, I think this could be a limitation, the problem is because I can't interact with native elements, I mean, I'm building sign in with Google, and after call a function on iOS it shows a dialog to confirm the login

[image]

But on integration tests I don't know how to interact with it

```dart
final buttonLoginFinder = find.byValueKey('login_button');
final buttonContinueFinder = find.text('Continue');
// ...

await driver.tap(buttonLoginFinder);
await driver.waitFor(buttonContinueFinder);
await driver.tap(buttonContinueFinder);
```

Comment: Unfortunately currently it's not possible to interact with such dialog via Flutter Driver. With Android device you could at least try to have some workaround using ADB, however after quick search It's most likely not possible to achieve with iOS/Xcode developer tools.
Somehow related issue on Github (which I think might be yours :-)) --> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12561

Comment: thxs :) @Wazniak

Answer (score -1):

From my point of view, this is not the right way to test your application.
Google Sign In should be considered as a black box.
So during the Integration Test, it should be mocked and just return true/false when trying to sign-in without particular dialogs interaction.
In this way, you can assume that Google Sign In as third part library works correctly and skip the integration test of an external component.

Comment: IMO this is a good hint. You should set a flag when starting your tests. (MyApp.IS_TEST_RUN = true;) In your code you should check if test is running or not. I have a service that is trying to access my location (= native permission dialog). In this service I add these lines " if (MyApp.IS_TEST_RUN){return defaultPosition;}". You can also use something like mockito then you don't have to touch your app code.